# Stanford Core NLP service not running correctly

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run Stanford CoreNLP Service by issuing the following command.

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp "*" -mx7g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000
-- listing properties --
port=9000
Starting server on port 9000 with timeout of 5000 milliseconds.
StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0.0.0.0:9000
[/127.0.0.1:52863] Interactive connection
[/127.0.0.1:52863] Interactive connection
```

Then, after accessing it's web interface from browser (http://127.0.0.1:9000/) I tried to enter a text and click Submit button. However the button does not react to the clicks and nothing happened. Besides that, the web interface differs from the original one ( [coreNLP interface screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5WoT.png) ). I tried to run coreNLP service on different servers(centos, windows) with different java versions (>1.8) with the same results. Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

Thank you,
Zaven.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford Core NLP start working in mysterious way. It’s non-working period coincides with problems with http://nlp.stanford.edu/ site. In the period when the service not worked the local Stanford core nlp not worked too.
I guess it tried to resolve nlp.stanford.edu failed and therefore cannot start the service. Could it be the case? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Is there a way to have it run locally without external dependencies like that?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the Stanford CoreNLP service is fine and works from the terminal. But what does not work correctly is the demo (localhost:9000 web app) which uses a script hosted from the domain `nlp.stanford.edu`. Thus when the domain is down, the demo breaks down too.